# Adding decimals together in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function which totals up three field values:

```
function calculatePublicTransportTotalClaim(){

    var Bus_Weekly_Claim = formatNum( $('#Bus_Weekly_Claim').val() );
    var Train_Weekly_Claim = formatNum( $('#Train_Weekly_Claim').val() );
    var Tram_Weekly_Claim = formatNum( $('#Tram_Weekly_Claim').val() );

    var Total = Bus_Weekly_Claim + Train_Weekly_Claim + Tram_Weekly_Claim;

    console.log( Total )

    $('#PublicTransport_Weekly_Claim').val( Total );

}
```

**The inputs have a default value of `0.00`**

And they have their values converted to `ints` using `formatNum` which looks like:

```
function formatNum(n) {

    var round = Math.round;

    n = round(n);

    return n.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
}
```

However when I call the function `calculatePublicTransportTotalClaim`, the returned `Total` is: `0.000.000.00`

What have I done wrong? As the values should now be numbers, but instead they seem to be acting like strings when I'm adding them together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toFixed` returns a string, and adding strings together does that.

As you're <s>replacing the period with a</s> adding commas, you'd have to do that after the numbers are added up, so the `formatNum` function isn't really usable, just do this instead

```
function calculatePublicTransportTotalClaim(){

    var Bus_Weekly_Claim   = Math.round( $('#Bus_Weekly_Claim').val() );
    var Train_Weekly_Claim = Math.round( $('#Train_Weekly_Claim').val() );
    var Tram_Weekly_Claim  = Math.round( $('#Tram_Weekly_Claim').val() );

    var Total = Bus_Weekly_Claim + Train_Weekly_Claim + Tram_Weekly_Claim;

    var parsedTotal = Total.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");

    $('#PublicTransport_Weekly_Claim').val( parsedTotal );

}
```

Comment: The regex replace doesn't replace the period with a comma.  It inserts commas around every myriad of 3 digits.

Comment: @MikeSamuel - Yes it does, didn't really read it I suppose, but same same, should be done *after* the numbers are added up.

Comment: No one is mentioning `parseFloat()`, am I being dumb?

Comment: @jacqijvv - isn't very usable either, `parseFloat( '123,665,443.33' ) == 123`

Comment: @MikeSamuel - I meant, *yes it does* what you say it does, **not** *yes it does*, as I don't agree with you, a bit ambiguous there ?

Comment: @adeneo, English is confusing, no?

Comment: @MikeSamuel - Yes it is, confusing that is !

Answer (score 1):

`toFixed()` returns a **string**

You are concatenating instead of adding.

Force it to return a number by adding `+`,

 e.g.
`return +(n.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,"));`

Answer (score 1):

Format the numbers after you added them together. Use parseFloat() to ensure they are being interpreted as decimal number values.

```
total = parseFloat(val1) + parseFloat(val2) + parseFloat(val3)
```

Then format the total, parseFloat() is JavaScript's equivalent to parseInt() but for decimal values

Note: you must not have commas, in the number when using parseFloat.  Always add formatting only after adding values.